# First answer queue showed me an answer by a long-time user

Tags: bug, new-users, specific-answer

My first answer queue today showed my this answer: [How to use structured bindings to set array's values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69291570/how-to-use-structured-bindings-to-set-arrays-values/69291592#69291592)

The answer history shows no edits. The answering user has been around since at least 2018 and has 153k points.

I was under the impression that first answer queues are for answers by new users. Is this a bug or did I completely miss the point here?

Screenshot of queue:
[image]

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog yes and no. I figured it out when I hit submit and saw the "This was only a test" message. I simply made the mistake of submitting to meta before suibmitting the queue response. Though the extra info is appreciated.

Comment: FYI that user has been around for 10 years and 3 months, it says it in their profile.

Answer (score 3):

> Congratulations!
> This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention. You passed.

[image]

Oh. Well then never mind.

Comment: I would close if I could.